# how to call onProgressUpdate method in asyntask in android

Tags: android

I implement the `AsynTask` in my code. I want to update my UI when `doInBackground()` task completed. But `onProgressupdate()` method is not calling. Please give us solution for this issue.

Comment: It is advisable in this forum to put up your code for ppl to help you out.

Comment: There are tons of tutorial on Internet for this. just google it.

Answer (score 4):

Call `publishProgress(...)` from your `doInBackground()`.